# Making a GeoTIFF using Google Earth Data

Tags: geotiff-tiff, proj, google-earth-pro

I'm trying to make a GeoTIFF using `geotifcp`, which I'll then upload to GeoServer.

I've got an image overlay (part of a `.kml`) in Google Earth, so I tried to use its bounding box to create a world file, which I could then feed to `geotifcp`.

In GeoServer, I've set the declared coordinate reference system to `EPGS:4326`, which I understand to match Google Earth. To upload the GeoTIFF to GeoServer, though, I need to also specify the native coordinate reference system of the GeoTIFF, which I should be able to do with `geotifcp` using a proj4 string.

[From here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/google-projection/), I got the proj4 string that should match Google Earth:

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

But when I use that with `geotifcp`,

```
geotifcp -e image.tfw -4 "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs" image.tif geotiff_image.tif
```

it returns this error:

```
mode=w
Failure in GTIFSetFromProj4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you using `geotifcp` to achieve? and why are you adding a mercator projection string? GeoServer will read a tiff+world file or you could use gdaltransform to make a geotiff

Comment: @IanTurton All I need in the end is a geotiff. I have an image overlay in Google Earth with the right alignment. I guess if `geotifcp` isn't the right tool, I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: I was trying to add a projection string because GeoServer said it was reading the tiff in as a "wildcard 2-dimensional coordinate reference system" (I believe), and as I understand, GeoServer would have to know what projection the coordinates in the geotiff (or world file) are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can add your raster to GeoServer, all of these require you to know what the projection of your data is (probably EPSG:4326 or WGS84 lat/lon).

1. Possibly the simplest, just tell GeoServer what the projection is after adding the data to the store. When you publish the layer simply fill in the declared SRS as EPSG:4326 and select `force declared` underneath. GeoServer will ignore it's "native" SRS guess and use your information.
2. You can convert your tiff + world file into a GeoTiff using [GDAL](https://gdal.org)'s [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) again you need to tell GDAL what projection you are using.

   ```
   gdal_translate -a_srs original.tif newgeotif.tif
   ```
3. You can provide a `.prj` file which contains the WKT representation of the projection you need - you can download these from http://epgs.io so yours would [this](http://epsg.io/4326.wkt). Like the `.wld` file this side car file can be read by other programs to tell them what the projection is.

Answer (score 1):

This is the projection you are looking for

https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

which has the following proj4 string

+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

Answer (score 1):

use proj4 string of EPSG:4326 in geotifcp

> +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

---

Also I suggest to use GDAL_TRANSLATE to create GeoTIFF which can be used directly in Geoserver.